# Powershell - How to add Column Widths

Tags: powershell

So I have looked on tons of stack overflows, Microsoft documentation, and websites to try and figure out how to add width spacing between my columns. I need it spaced out because this data is going to be sent in an email

Code:

```
#!ps

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(160,5000)
Get-ADUser -Filter *  -Properties * | ft Name, UserPrincipalName, Created, lastLogonDate
```

when I run this I get all my data but its all squished together and I want it to have a decent amount of spacing between each column. Ive tried `-AutoSize` and all these other ways but nothing seems to work

Comment: If you need fomratting in emails I'd recommend using html formatting. Otherwise you'd need to use string manipulation to get the text formatted to your needs.

Comment: well im using this code inside of a script which sends the email at the end of the script so as long as it looks good in powershell it should produce the same output for the email

Comment: If the email application you receive this email with displays the email with an unproportional font you might be right. Try `Out-String` instead of `Format-Table`.

Comment: so like literally replacing "ft" with "Out-String" ? I tried that and im getting an error

Comment: @MrClayGiovanni - unless you are adding HTML code to your email body that tells the email app to render the text as monospaced text, it will NOT line wrap at line ends. you need the HTML 'break' code for that.

Comment: its kinda hard to explain but im using a software called ConnectWise automate which is for automation. and im having a line where it runs a powershell command and the results are saved as a variable and then the variable is placed in the body of the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$fmtADUser = 
      @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";Width=[xxx]},
      @{Expression={$_.UserPrincipalName};Label="Principal Name";Width=[xxx]},
      @{Expression={$_.Created};Label="Created";Width=[xxx]},
      @{Expression={$_.lastLogonDate};Label="Last Logon Date";Width=[xxx]}

$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(160,5000)
$AdUserInfo = Get-ADUser -Filter *  -Properties * | 
              Format-Table -Property $fmtADUser | 
              Out-String -Width [www]
              
#--- Replace [xxx] with the desired column width.
#--- Replace [www] with the total of all columns plus 2 for spacing between each column.
```

Comment: so I made an edit to add $ADUserInfo at the end because that's needed to show the results. however, the widths are not changing when ive done different numbers

Comment: If you just want to show results on the console just remove the $AdUserInfo = , rather than adding another line, unless you will use it later.

Comment: I posted it on the page

Comment: so I just realized that I accidently didn't copy a line of code over from what you created and it does actually work. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a styled table from the data in the email, but want to show it as seen in the console, I would suggest capturing the result in a string variable, and add that to the body variable you have wrapped in [<pre>..</pre>](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_pre_tag.htm) tags.

```
# properties Name and UserPrincipalName are returned by default
# capture the output as string in variable $result
$result = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Created, LastLogonDate | 
          Format-Table Name, UserPrincipalName, Created, LastLogonDate -AutoSize |
          Out-String

# show in the console
$result

# add the result to the body of the email variable, wrapped in '<pre>..</pre>' tags, 
# so it is displayed in a fixed-width font, and it preserves both spaces and line breaks
# add a HTML linebreak in front too.
$body += "<br><pre>$result</pre>"
```